# ssh as user runs program with no authentication (neither password nor keys)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, pam

I'd like to set up a user on my system (Ubuntu 14.04 x64) such that people can run `ssh example@myhost.example.com` and see some output from a program without being prompted for a password or having to have an ssh key. Here's what I have done so far:

- created the `example` user with my program as it's shell via `adduser example --shell /path/to/my/program`
- created an empty file at `/home/example/.hushlogin` to quiet the motd and other login messages

Things are working with the exception that I must complete the password prompt authentication challenge, which I'd like to bypass as this will be a publicly-available service.

Presumably customizing the PAM configuration under `/etc/pam.d` appropriately might do the trick but I need some guidance on the specifics. I want this change to only affect this specific user account, not every account on the system.

Comment: Use ssh auth with keys. Commands are ssh-keygen and ssh-copy-id

Comment: I want this to be a publicly-available program without any authentication whatsoever. I'm not asking about using ssh keys instead of passwords. I'm asking about using neither.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using SSH instead of something that is designed for extending in this fashion, i.e. [SNMP](http://sysadvent.blogspot.com/2008/12/day-4-extending-net-snmps-snmpd.html)? A lot more can go wrong when a user is authenticated to a SSH subsystem compared to being shown the unauthenticated output of a command via SNMP.

Comment: Mostly because I need a reverse tunnel to have my program access hosts via the end user's system intermediary. I also want the encryption over the wire and the fact that my end users already have ssh clients installed on their systems.

Answer (score 3):

Set `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and then make sure the user account has no password.

Comment: You can set this with Match User <specific user> in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: Is `passwd -d example` the right way to make sure the user account has no password? I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting prompted and just hitting ENTER does not get past the password prompt.

Comment: Thought about this some more and my line of thinking leads me to believe `PermitEmptyPasswords` would never bypass the password prompt. I don't believe sshd has any system API it can call to ask "is user1's password empty?". It can only ask the system "is this the correct password for user1?" I think `PermitEmptyPasswords` just controls whether sshd automatically reprompts on empty password input without even attempting authentication.